# Only emulators can connect to server running on PC, not actual devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator

I have an app that connects to a server using `Sockets`. If I run the app on an emulator and the server on the same PC, they connect just fine. If I run the app on my SGS Vibrant and try to connect to the same server on the same PC, nothing happens. The server is a standalone Java program I have written. I have disabled Windows Firewall and I haven't installed any kind of firewall on my phone. The phone and my computer are connected to the same WiFi connection. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to connect via telnet or other client application from another pc on the same wifi network?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a network interface issue--verify that you're either listening on all interfaces or on the correct one.

Comment: I can successfully do things like play a LAN game of TF2 and access local network shares, so it isn't a connectivity issue. How would I define what interfaces I'm listening on? I never had to specify one when I defined my `Socket`.

Comment: @notverycreative: What IP address is your server software 'listening' on? How are you trying to connect to it from the device (e.g., WiFi etc)?

Comment: My server is listening on its local IP of 192.168.56.1. Both my computer and phone are connected to the same WiFi network and both have connectivity.

Comment: Ohhhh, I may have figured it out. 192.168.56.1 is the IP of my VirtualBox virtual networking device, while my actual IP (the wireless one) is 192.168.0.121.

Comment: @notverycreative: You can specify local address and port with the `Socket.bind(SocketAddress localAddr)` method.